Github/Cloudflare Website With A PhaserJS Web Game Not Updating Online
I have a website on this repo: https://github.com/LeftClickMage/ethantwu.com/tree/main/minigames/greenearth, which links to this page: https://ethantwu.com/minigames/greenearth, and for some reason, it does not update if you have already opened the page before. All pages on my website updates by just reloading, so this is surprising.
I recently posted this game I created with phaser, and kept developing it. When I decided update 1.1 was ready, I pushed the update to github. Then to my surprise, the website still showed version 1.0 after reloading.

I have tried everything I could think of to get this page to update. First, I tried to clear cache, which to my surprise did not work. Then I tried to purge all cache from cloudflare (runs my website), which also did not work.

Then I turned on developer mode on cloudflare, which bypasses all cache for all clients, which also did not work.

Then out of frustration I cleared all code from the index.js file, which runs the game. Which then STILL showed the game version 1.0. IT RAN WITH NO CODE!
Then I deleted the entire directory from github, which finally deleted the page. Then I pushed the new code back on, and then it still showed V 1.0.
I tried on different devices, asked a friend who has opened the page before to try, nothing worked. The only way the page “updated” was when someone who has never opened the page before tried to open it. This confused me as I have practically wiped all of the cache from the website off the face of the earth.
I would really appreciate some help with this as I gave it some time(I thought time was an issue), and it still has not updated.

I removed the phaser-framework tag, due to the fact that this is no phaser-framework issue (since phaser does cache anything), it possibly has to do with  cloudflare and/or github. It best to keep tags to the essentials to.

Okay! Thanks @winner_joiner

No Problem, btw. I tested your game. Just wanted to feedback I like the idea.

That means a lot to me! Also, @winner_joiner I gave it some more time, and it seems to have updated. Is there a way to add my own answer or close the question? I think the answer was purging cache, and then waiting atleast 4 hours.

Sure you can answer you own question, there should be a button below. (it's the only way how to earn the SO Badge "Self-Learner" ;-) )

maybe you can try to write to the Cloudflare support?

@LeftClickMage btw.: for self answering your question you need to wait 48 hour, until you can accept your answer. link to SO article

I am pretty sure the answer is to wait for some time. I gave it around 12 hours overnight, and then it worked the next day. I will try and make a cache rule that tells cloudflare not to cache these files! But normally they cache files for 4 hours, so I would recommend purging cache and then waiting for at least 4 hours!
If anyone wants to have version control to allow caching but updating, I think this might solve your problem: How to prevent caching of my Javascript file?
